# Request for merging tag [user-activity] and [user-activities]

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

Both tags [user-activity](/questions/tagged/user-activity) and [user-activities](/questions/tagged/user-activities) are talking about the same thing.

Also, I suggest to synonym [user-behavior](/questions/tagged/user-behavior) to the above tag.

Comment: Two of those tags don't seem to have any questions... (I see RSS links, meaning they probably did not long ago.)

Comment: @michaelb958 - RSS link is displayed [by default](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/michaelb958) even if the tag doesn't exist. :D

Comment: @hims056 `1` TIL there's always an RSS link; `2` *\*becomes unnecessarily excited about tag named after self\**